# Why did the CONSENFOLP callback assertion fail when the problem has a primal feasible solution?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, callback, scip

I am working on the problem that I am willing to use SCIP's `conshdlr` callback to check how the constraints might be added to the model. I am using the following manner:

```py
    class MyConshdlr(Conshdlr):
    
        ## fundamental callbacks ##
        def consenfolp(self, constraints, nusefulconss, solinfeasible):
        calls.add("consenfolp")
        for constraint in constraints:
          assert id(constraint) in ids
        return {"result": SCIP_RESULT.FEASIBLE}
    
        def consenfops(self, constraints, nusefulconss, solinfeasible, objinfeasible):
        calls.add("consenfolp")
        for constraint in constraints:
          assert id(constraint) in ids
        return {"result": SCIP_RESULT.FEASIBLE}
    
    
        def conscheck(self, constraints, solution, checkintegrality, checklprows, printreason, completely):
        calls.add("conscheck")
        for constraint in constraints:
          assert id(constraint) in ids
        return {"result": SCIP_RESULT.FEASIBLE}
    
        def conslock(self, constraint, locktype, nlockspos, nlocksneg):
        calls.add("conslock")
        assert id(constraint) in ids
    
        ## Optinal callbacks ##
        def consactive(self, constraint):
        calls.add("consactive")
        assert id(constraint) in ids
    
        def consgetnvars(self, constraint):
        calls.add("consgetnvars")
        assert id(constraint) in ids
        return {"nvars": 1, "success": True}
        
        def test_conshdlr():
    
            def create_model():
                # create solver instance
                s = Model()
    
    
                # Optimization model
                ...
    
                # create conshdlr and include it to SCIP
                conshdlr = MyConshdlr()
                s.includeConshdlr()
                
                # creating constraint
                cons1 = s.createCons()
                ...
    
                # add these constraints
                s.addPyCons()
                ...
                
                return s
    
            s = create_model()
            # solve problem
            s.optimize()
    
            del s
            assert "consenfolp" in calls
            assert "consenfops" in calls
            assert "conscheck" in calls
            assert "conslock" in calls
            assert "consactive" in calls
```

As long as the problem is solved by the usual paradigm, the solver returns the optimal solution, but when I add the constraints by callbacks, it throws an issue as follows:

```py
    AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-7-9a59f5f7b72a> in <cell line: 154>()
        153 
        154 if __name__ == "__main__":
    --> 155   test_conshdlr()
    
    <ipython-input-7-9a59f5f7b72a> in test_conshdlr()
        137   del s
        138 
    --> 139   assert "consenfolp" in calls
    
    AssertionError:
```

Also, I have a look at SCIP's documents where `CONSENFOLP` is defined as:

> The CONSENFOLP method is called after the price-and-cut loop was
> finished and an LP solution is available. Like the CHECK call, the
> ENFOLP method should return a result SCIP_FEASIBLE, if the solution
> satisfies all the constraints. However, the behavior should be
> different, if the solution violates some of the associated
> constraints. The constraint handler may return a result
> SCIP_INFEASIBLE in this situation, but this is not the best what one
> can do.

Now, my questions are:

- What does exactly `CONSENFOLP` mean? and how does it work?
- As the other callbacks seem to work fine, how is it possible to reject the solution by `CONSENFOLP`?